# Why am I getting a NullPointerException with arrays in Java?

Tags: java, exception, pointers, null

```
public static byte[] main_Mem = new byte[2048];
public static SlotNode[] cache = new SlotNode[8];
```

Doesn't this create instances of the objects? Why would I be getting a NPE?

```
 //initialize main memory
           for (int i = 0; i<main_Mem.length; i++) {
                   main_Mem[i] = (byte) (0xFF & i);
                   System.out.printf("%X", 0xFF & i);
                   System.out.print("      " + i);
                   System.out.println(" ");

           }

           //initialize cache slots to 0
           for (int i = 0; i<cache.length; i++) {
                   cache[i].setValidBit(0);
                   cache[i].setTag(0);
                   cache[i].setData(0);
                   cache[i].setDirty(0);
           }
```

Comment: **Use a debugger.** No, it clearly does _not_ instantiate any `SlotNodes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to init the SlotNode, such as this:

```
   for (int i = 0; i<cache.length; i++) {
           cache[i] = new SlotNode(...); // Add the constructor parameters as needed
           cache[i].setValidBit(0);
           cache[i].setTag(0);
           cache[i].setData(0);
           cache[i].setDirty(0);
   }
```

By doing this:

```
public static SlotNode[] cache = new SlotNode[8];
```

you just initialize the **array** of 8 `SlotNode` instances - you need to initialize each of them separately.

Comment: Yes; I'd recommend a static initializer.

Comment: @Jackie Sure thing, glad to help! @dyffymo Yes, depending on what `SlotNode` is, that can make perfect sense.

Comment: I said that not because of the type, but because it's declared as static.

Answer (score 3):

No, allocating memory for the arrays is not the same thing as allocating objects.

The array cache has 8 references of type SlotNode, all set to null until you assign them to point to a SlotNode instance.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
new SlotNode[8]
```

Only creates an array of 8 `SlotNode` references. They're all initialized to `null` by default, so you have to initialize them yourself later. For instance, in the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<cache.length; i++) {
    cache[i] = new SlotNode(); // initialize the object
    cache[i].setValidBit(0);
    cache[i].setTag(0);
    cache[i].setDirty(0);
}
```